# How to add mozSystem property to $http service in angular?

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, firefox-os

Change jquery to angular in my application, but do not know how this property is added to the service $http, was something in jquery:
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});

more information:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/7903#issuecomment-49966671

[Firefox OS packaged apps and XMLHttpRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873025/firefox-os-packaged-apps-and-xmlhttprequests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## As of 2015-April-30 (AngularJS v1.3.15)

There is no way to dynamically create an XHR object in angular, but it is being discussed.

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/9319

## Angular Modified for FxOS

Here are patched versions of angular that only vary in that their XHR has been patched for use with systemXHR on FxOS

- [AngularJS for Firefox OS](https://gist.github.com/coolaj86/459266f6c42db7a7474c)
- [angular-1.3.15-fxos.js](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/coolaj86/459266f6c42db7a7474c/raw/angular-1.3.15-fxos.js)
- [angular-1.3.15-fxos.min.js](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/coolaj86/459266f6c42db7a7474c/raw/angular-1.3.15-fxos.min.js)

**Note**: Don't try to use those links as a CDN.

## Workaround

https://angularjs.org/ has a CDN link from which you can download the latest version (which is fine, because you're going to be packaging the app on the device anyway).

For example:
* https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js

You'll probably want the **uncompressed** source so that it's easier to work with.

**Search** in the file for `XHR`, `createXHR`, or `XMLHttpRequest` and you'll see function that needs to be patched.

As stated by @jan you'll be replacing something that looks like

```
return new window.XMLHttpRequest()
```

with

```
return new window.XMLHttpRequest({ mozSystem: true })
```

You can either minify the file using `uglify-js`, download and edit the minified version (if that's not too scary for you), or go commando and use the unminified version.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some framework hacking actually at the moment. In angular.js file, look for

```
var XHR = window.XMLHttpRequest || function() {
  try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); } catch (e1) {}
  try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); } catch (e2) {}
  try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e3) {}
  throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
};
```

And replace it by:

```
var XHR = function(){
  return new window.XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to first config HTTP header

```
// Define HTTP header for .NET
.config(function($httpProvider, $routeProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
    var param = function(obj){
        var query = '', name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;

        for(name in obj){
            value = obj[name];

            if(value instanceof Array){
                for(i=0; i<valuel.length; ++i){
                    subValue = value[i];
                    fullSubName = name + '[' + i +']';
                    innerObj = {};
                    innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                    query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                }
            }
            else if(value instanceof Object) {
                for(subName in value) {
                    subValue = value[subName];
                    fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
                    innerObj = {};
                    innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                    query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                }
            }
            else if(value !== undefined && value !== null)
                query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
        }

        return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
    };

    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data){
        return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? param(data) : data;
    }];

})
```

Once you configured HTTP header. You need URL for HTTP method. Angular's $HTTP return promise. You can call async HTTP request if you needed.

Here is the example of code

```
.service('PromisesQ',function AjaxService($http, $q){
    var ajaxService = this; 

    ajaxService.countTargetRecords = function countTargetRecords(targetXML){
        var AjaxURL =  url_dev;
        var AjaxData = 'InputParam1=input&InputParam2=anotherInput;

        return $http.post(AjaxURL, AjaxData)
                    .success(function(response){
                        return response;
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log('[CountTargetRecords] Error '+ data);
                    })
    }
```

Hope this helpful.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question being asked.